# Cannot use Entity Framework in .NET standard 2 project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-standard-2.0

How can I use Entity Framework, or something similar within a .NET Standard project?

It appears as though EF is not supported in .NET Standard 2 which is really annoying!

So I have tried using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and icrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design

Whist I can install these packages, I cannot then add a model

I get the error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
The project's target framework does not contain Entity Framework runtime assemblies. Please review the target framework information in the project's property page.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I get around this?

I am seriously thinking to get rid of .NET Standard out of all my projects but that is a bit drastic!

Paul

Comment: It's not. EF 6 came years before .NET Standard 2.0. The .NET Standard compatilbe version is EF Core.

Comment: Is it not possible to have a visual model designer for EF Core?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the actual question is "How can I create models and reverse engineer a database using EF Core like I could with EF 6" ?

The tooling is separate from the NuGet package. Visual Studio 2017 doesn't include modelling or reverse engineer tools for EF Core. Those are available through [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) an open source addon. You can find the code and documentation [here](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF-Core-Power-Tools)

Comment: When I try to use this I get another error Currently only .NET Framework and .NET Core 2.0 projects are supported - TargetFrameworkMoniker: .NETStandard,Version=v2.0

Comment: The tooling for EF doesn't fully work with a project that targets only .NET Standard.  But the runtime does.  Try running the tooling in a console app targeting .NET core and moving the generated code artifacts into your .NET Standard class library.

Answer (score 0):

Change the EF version. There are some versions of EF that work with NetStandard2.0 but other (recently ones) usually don't.

For example with the version 6:
[image]

And with version 5, you can use it in a Standard project:

[image]