# In Asp.net Web Api project error 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'DataLayer' (class library)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have one class library (.net standard) named 'DataLayer' and one web API project in the solution.

After right click on DataLayer and going on manage nuget package, when I try to install entity framework, it is giving an error message:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'DataLayer'

I have already tried clear all nuget cache.

But the error still the same. what should I do?

Comment: Try closing Visual Studio, packages should be restored when it’s reopened.. Also check packages.config for correct versions, in output window enable all errors, check for missing references in the bin..

Comment: Package EntityFramework 6.2.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.4 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.4). Package EntityFramework 6.2.0 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.4.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'DataLayer'

Comment: Need to figure out combining .NetStandard and .Net framework https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7035edc6-97fc-49ee-8eee-2fa4d040a63b/what-are-differences-between-net-framwork-net-standard-and-net-core?forum=clr

Comment: so i need to upgrade the framework ?

Comment: Not sure but here it says you should use .Net Core with .NetStandard for compatibility reasons.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48582603/3254405

Comment: ok, now i've created .net core class library and tried to install entity framework again but still same error 'package restore failed'              Package EntityFramework 6.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package EntityFramework 6.2.0 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Comment: Do you have to use EF6? It’s the one causing the error.. Try EF Core..

Comment: Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.3.
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.3 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.

Comment: Hm, at this time you should upgrade.. From .NetStandard 1.4 to 2.0 (but no guarantees)..

Comment: okay, thanks a lot :)